# Migrating questions as a user – Fragen als Nutzer migrieren

Tags: feature-request, migration

I just wanted to vote for closing this question: [Could you spell Dutch according to the German system?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28807/1487). As reason I wanted to say that it should be migrated to Linguistics SE. So I clicked:

- close
- off-topic because ...
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

And then there is a list of possible targets, but this list contains only one item: German Language Meta. But I want to recommend migration to Linguistics SE.

How can I do this?

---

Ich wollte gerade diese Frage schließen:
[Could you spell Dutch according to the German system?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28807/1487).
Als Grund wollte ich angeben, dass sie nach Linguistics SE migriert werden soll.
Also klickte ich:

- close
- off-topic because ...
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Dann gibt es eine Liste mit möglichen Zielen, die aber nur einen Eintrag enthält: German Language Meta. Ich möchte aber nach Linguistics SE migrieren bzw. dies vorschlagen oder dafür stimmen.

Wie kann ich das tun?

---

**Ergänzung:**

Ich habe mich anscheinend schlecht ausgedrückt (kommt davon, wenn man in einer Fremdsprache schreibt).

Ich möchte die Frage nicht sofort nach Linguistics verschieben. Ich möchte auch nicht das Recht haben, das tun zu können. So etwas sollte eine Mehrheitsentscheidung bleiben, und von mir aus auch der Zustimmung eines Moderators bedürfen.

Aber ich möchte das Schließen der Frage vorschlagen dürfen, um die Community darüber entscheiden zu lassen. Das darf ich ja prinzipiell. Aber dazu muss ich auch einen Grund angeben (was auch gut so ist). Und diese Begründung meines Schließ-Wunsches lautet: Die Frage ist hier in German.SE off-topic und sollte zu einer anderen Seite verschoben werden, nämlich nach Linguistics.SE.

Ich kann zwar anklicken, dass die Frage off-topic ist, und ich kann auch anklicken,dass sie verschoben werden sollte, aber ich kann das meiner Meinung nach passende Ziel der Verschiebung nicht angeben, und somit meinen Close-Vorschlag nicht abschließen.

Daher bitte ich darum, Linguistics.SE, English.SE, und ein paar andere Seiten, die in einem Naheverhältnis zu German.SE stehen, in jene Liste der erlaubten Migrations-Ziele aufzunehmen, in der derzeit nur Meta.German.SE steht.

Comment: Ich muss sagen, dass ich etwas überrascht bin, dass Du nicht [auf Deutsch gepostet](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1086/2594) hast.

Comment: Oh, darf man auf Meta jetzt auf Deutsch posten? das wusste ich nicht. Super, dass das jetzt geht. Danke für den Hinweis!

Answer (score 6):

> How can I do this?

You can’t. Migration by close voters (via “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network”) is only activated in frequently used cases on some sites where the moderators cannot handle the load (and from Main to Meta). Every other migration can only be performed by moderators. We have so few migrations that moderators can handle this without problem.

Migration should only happen with questions that are off-topic, anyway. Therefore, what you should do is choose a custom close reason and elaborate why this question is off-topic and also state on which site it would be on-topic. If it gets closed or you are confident that it will be, you can flag it for moderator attention asking to migrate it. However, such migrations should be the exception – most often it is best if the asker re-asks the question on the appropriate site.

In the specific case, I would consider the question on-topic on both German Language and Linguistics, and am uncertain where it will receive better answers. I thus would prefer not to migrate it and would not do so unless the community decides it to be off-topic.

---

> Wie kann ich das tun?

Gar nicht. Migration durch Schließstimmen (via »This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network«) ist nur für einige häufig genutzte Fälle auf einigen Seiten aktiviert, wenn die Moderatoren den Anfragen nicht hinterherkommen (und von der Hauptseite nach Meta). Jede andere Migration können nur Moderatoren durchführen. Die wenigen Migrationen, die wir haben, können die Moderatoren problemlos bearbeiten.

Migration sollte sowieso nur mit Fragen passieren, die off-topic sind. Was Du daher tun solltest, ist einen maßgeschneiderten Schließgrund zu wählen, zu erklären warum die Frage off-topic ist und anzugeben, auf welche Seite die Frage passen würde. Wenn die Frage geschlossen wird oder Du sicher bist, dass dies passieren wird, bitte einen Moderator, sie zu migrieren *(flag → in need of moderator intervention).*  Allerdings sollten solche Migrationen die Ausnahme bleiben – häufig ist es besser wenn der Fragesteller die Frage auf der richtigen Seite neu stellt.

Das Fallbeispiel würde ich sowohl auf unserer Seite als auch Linguistic SE für on-topic halten, und ich kann nicht sagen, wo es die besten Antworten erhält. Ich würde daher vorziehen, die Frage nicht zu migrieren und dies auch nicht tun, es sei denn die Community entscheidet, dass die Frage off-topic ist.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear: I don't want to immediately migrate the question. I want to suggest/flag to close it in German.SE because it is off-topic here and should be migrated to Linguistics.SE. But I can't suggest the off-topic-closing because I can't name the correct reason for closing.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: What’s wrong with *Close → Off-topic → Other?*

Comment: Warum sollte ich »Other« auswählen, wenn der Punkt darüber (*This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*) genau der richtige ist? Gebt diesen Punkt weg, dann bleibt mir eh nur »Other«. Aber dann könnt ihr gleich alle Punkte außer »Other« weggeben. Denn wozu sollte ich den genau passenden Grund anklicken, wenn ich - deinem Vorschlag folgend - »Other« auswählen sollte?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Der Punkt darüber ist nun mal halt für feste Migrationspfade vorgesehen, auch wenn die Bezeichnung vermuten lässt, dass es für alles geht. Deshalb ist *Other* hier die beste Wahl. Wenn Dir das nicht passt, musst Du Dich auf [meta.se] beschweren und eine bessere Wortwahl vorschlagen. Ich habe selbst [einen Feature-Wunsch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273544/255554) geäußert, der in die Richtung geht.

Comment: @Hubert Migrationspfade existieren ja prinzipiell nur, damit Moderatoren der großen Seiten Arbeit abgenommen wird. Wenn ich das richtig verstanden habe, dann kommen die bei SO mit ihren Flaggen so schon nicht hinterher. Wenn sie dann auch noch ständig zu SU oder programmers o.ä. migrieren würden, dann würde es ja nur noch mehr werden. Auf kleinen Seiten, sollte man den Umweg dann schon noch über den Moderator machen. Im Zweifel kann der dann nochmal nachfragen ob die Frage beim Ziel auch angenommen wird. Dann entsteht weniger "Müll" der hin- und hergeschoben wird...

Answer (score 2):

Only moderators can migrate a question to a site not in the list (assuming the recipient site is willing to take it). You can therefore raise a custom flag (“in need of moderator attention”) and ask them to migrate the question.

In principle, the list of possible targets can be extended, but this isn’t done for beta sites.

Comment: Das (Migrationspfade) wird nicht mal häufig für kleine graduierte Seiten gemacht. Der Aufwand ist es oft einfach nicht wert. Ich hab das auf chem.se mal gecheckt, wir hatten im letzten Jahr zwischen 10-20 erfolgreiche Migrationen. Ich weiß nicht, wieviele hier migriert werden, aber ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass es mehr ist.

Comment: @Martin sehr wichtiger und interessanter Punkt!